# How to remove a directory that no longer exists but is in the history of mecurial

Tags: bitbucket

I'm using the free plan on bitbucket to hold a repo in mecurial.  There is one other person using the repo with me.  When we first started we were putting everything into the repo.  That included a folder called documents that held a ton of pdf files.  We have now excluded that folder but all those documents and their history are still in our repo.  The free version of bitbucket allows for a repo of 2 gig.  I'd like to remove the history of this documents folder from the history because we are  closer to the 2 gig limit then i'd like to be.  Is there a good way to get rid of that history.  What are my options.  I'm not finding much online but that could very well be because i'm using the wrong words to search.

I tried to use hg remove Documents* but that didn't work because it's telling me that there are no tracked files.

Update -- 
I looked in TortoiseHg and on rev 91 i added a ton of files in the Documents folder (it has sub folders as well if that matters).  So I think that is likely where the size of the repo blew up.  So if anyone knows how to remove those from history i'd be interested..  and is it safe to remove them.  We do not need them in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to remove history is to create a new repo using [hg convert](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension)

1. Before you start you tell everyone to stop using the repo.
2. then your run `hg convert` specifying the files you want to exclude.
3. Once you are done you tell everyone to start using the new repo.